# Create date as dd/mm/yyyy formate in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, sh

Please I am trying to create table with date in it.

```
CREATE TABLE ticket(
  TicketID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  AirlineID INTEGER,
  PassengerID INTEGER,
  TicketDate DATE('NOW'),
  TicketPrice INTEGER,
  TicketVolume INTEGER,
  DestinationCountry INTEGER,
  ExitCountry INTEGER
);
```

However, the default date format is dd-mm-yyyy, but I would like to use the format dd/mm/yyyy. How can I do this.

Comment: Hint:  `date_format()` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Comment: Dates don't have a format, a format is applied when the value is displayed, but internally it is just a number.

Comment: MySQL displays and accepts date (and datetime) values that use the standard format `YYYY-MM-DD`. It is up to your application to format the dates it displays using a different format. You can also use the function [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to ask MySQL to format a date column it returns using a custom format.

Comment: Yes but I have a csv file to import with the dd/mm/yyyy format.

Comment: @DestinyAlabi In that case you have to pre-process the data and then store it in csv.

Answer (score 0):

When I see that you tag your question as bash and sh, I suppose that you are coding in bash for connecting the CSV file your are speaking about in a comment above with a mysql client.

Try to convert the date as follows:

```
date_from_csv="31/01/2018"
date_for_mysql=${date_from_csv//\//-}
echo $date_for_mysql
```

The code above changes every occurence of '/' from the string of the date into '-'. Since the '/' you want to substitute can be confused with the separator, you have to escape it as '\/'.

Comment: Will try that. Thanks